# Uneven / Custom-Positioned Axis Labels in Chart.JS

Tags: chart.js, axis-labels, chart.js2

I'm trying to migrate an existing library for generating scatter plots from Python to Chart.js that look like this:
[image]

But I'm struggling with how to create the X-Axis labels at such uneven horizontal positions with Chart.js v2.9.4 (I don't need to replicate the vertical offsets at this time)
[image]

Any suggestions/examples of how I might do this?

-Brett

Comment: Can you give a code example of your scatter chart?